# How to control change stream output using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, changestream

I am trying Mongodb [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) using [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/change-streams.html):

```js
Person.watch().on('change', data => console.log(data));
```

It tracked all the change of the database, is it possible to apply condition and track certain documents instead, like how to check `id`==1 and `id`==2 documents only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this on the model. But assuming you can, you probably can pass a pipeline to filter the input docs. I personnaly use watch on the DB and it works fine.

Here, i use the `{fullDocument:"updateLookup"}` option to add the whole object to results. I can then match the `id` with simple `$in` query operator.

```
Person.watch( [
      {
        $match: {
          "fullDocument.id": {"$in" : [1,2]},       
        },
      },
    ],
    {
      fullDocument: "updateLookup",
    }).on('change', data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, is it a must to have `{fullDocument: "updateLookup",}`? cause I tried with `{$match:{id:{$in: [1,2]}}}` before, it didn't work.

Comment: It depends ! You can match on anything you want really. 
For example, i only want to listen changes on update events, so in my match i put           `"updateDescription.updatedFields.value": { $exists: true },
          operationType: "update",`
You should log data as you did, see what data you get. Then, match according the thing you want. The _id might be always in data but i'm not sure.